# Adding a Tooltip in D3 to a Google Maps Overlay

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm currently trying to extend this example http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/899711 by adding tooltips for each marker. However, I've been pretty unsuccessful in the process. I've tried following procedures outlined in the following post:

http://bl.ocks.org/biovisualize/1016860

I tried adding mouseover and mouseout listeners to the original example by they don't work. The modifications to the original example are below:

```
var tooltip = d3.select("body")
    .append("div")
    .style("position", "absolute")
    .style("z-index", "10")
    .style("visibility", "hidden")
    .text("a simple tooltip");

marker.append("svg:circle")
    .attr("r", 4.5)
    .attr("cx", padding)
    .attr("cy", padding)
    .on("mouseover", function(){console.log("mousover"); return tooltip.style("visibility", "visible");})
    .on("mousemove", function(){return tooltip.style("top", (event.pageY-10)+"px").style("left",(event.pageX+10)+"px");})
    .on("mouseout", function(){return tooltip.style("visibility", "hidden");});;
```

Thanks for any help given!

Comment: Try D3 [tip](https://github.com/Caged/d3-tip) library

Comment: Did you get the solution? Please post it.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the z-index of the elements. The google map is stacked on top of the svg elements. Therefore the mouse events cannot be registered.